# App automatically crashes after some time on text watcher filter list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview, textwatcher

I am using filter search for recyclerview.My app crashes automatically after some time,it looks like that text watcher is calling automatically.

I am getting this error

```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> com.qasoftearth.abcipl.Adapter.ProductAdapter.filterList(java.util.ArrayList)'
> on a null object reference
>         at com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity.filter(NavDrawerActivity.java:288)
>         at com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity.access$100(NavDrawerActivity.java:60)
>         at com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity$2.afterTextChanged(NavDrawerActivity.java:168)



**
```

> > E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >         Process: com.qasoftearth.abcipl, PID: 22202
> >         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.qasoftearth.abcipl/com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity}:
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> >     com.qasoftearth.abcipl.Adapter.ProductAdapter.filterList(java.util.ArrayList)'
> >     on a null object reference
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4336)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
> >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
> >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
> >          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> >     com.qasoftearth.abcipl.Adapter.ProductAdapter.filterList(java.util.ArrayList)'
> >     on a null object reference
> >             at com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity.filter(NavDrawerActivity.java:288)
> >             at com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity.access$100(NavDrawerActivity.java:60)
> >             at com.qasoftearth.abcipl.NavDrawerActivity$2.afterTextChanged(NavDrawerActivity.java:168)
> >             at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8356)
> >             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4419)
> >             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4252)
> >             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)
> >             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4227)
> >             at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:4120)
> >             at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14957)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3264)
> >             at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14935)
> >             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2123)
> >             at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1024)
> >             at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:979)
> >             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1171)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2551)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4336) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
> >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
> >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

**

**NavDrawerActivity.java**

```
public class NavDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    EditText search_edittext;
    TextView viewCart,orderNow,addToCart,txtItemName,txtItemModelNum,txtItemDescriptions;

    RecyclerView recyclerViewCategory,recyclerViewProduct;
    ArrayList<CategoryDataModel> categoryArrayList;
    ArrayList<ProductModelClass> productModelClassList;
    ProductAdapter productAdapter;
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    MyReceiver receiver;

    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerContainer;
    SharedPrefLogin sharedPrefLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        sharedPrefLogout=new SharedPrefLogin(getApplicationContext());


        categoryArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        productModelClassList=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewCategory = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_horizontal);
        recyclerViewProduct = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_product_list);
        search_edittext=findViewById(R.id.search_edittext);
        viewCart=findViewById(R.id.txtv_viewCart);
        orderNow=findViewById(R.id.txtv_OrderNow);
        addToCart=findViewById(R.id.txtvAddToCart);

        txtItemName=findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
        txtItemModelNum=findViewById(R.id.txtItemModelNum);
        txtItemDescriptions=findViewById(R.id.txtItemDescriptions);

        shimmerContainer = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);

        shimmerContainer.startShimmerAnimation();

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Constants.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

        if(InternetUtils.checkForInternet(getApplicationContext()))
        {

            fetchJSON();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!InternetUtils.checkForInternet(getApplicationContext())) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("No Internet Connection");

                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Please check your internet connection. ")
                        .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            receiver = new MyReceiver();
            registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

        }



        //adding a TextChangedListener
        //to call a method whenever there is some change on the EditText
        search_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                //after the change calling the method and passing the search input

                    filter(editable.toString());


            }
        });

        search_edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    search_edittext.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search_edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        viewCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent viewCart=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this,CartListActivity.class);
                startActivity(viewCart);
            }
        });


        //*************************************Recyclerview Category**********************************************************


        recyclerViewCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);

        categoryArrayList.add(new CategoryDataModel("All Categories",R.drawable.delhi));
        categoryArrayList.add(new CategoryDataModel("Fashion",R.drawable.delhi));
        categoryArrayList.add(new CategoryDataModel("Mobile and \nElectronics",R.drawable.delhi));
        categoryArrayList.add(new CategoryDataModel("Home and \n Living",R.drawable.delhi));
        categoryArrayList.add(new CategoryDataModel("Daily Needs",R.drawable.delhi));
        categoryArrayList.add(new CategoryDataModel("Books",R.drawable.delhi));

        recyclerViewCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryArrayList);
        recyclerViewCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        shimmerContainer.startShimmerAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        shimmerContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
        super.onPause();
    }


    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Constants.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)){
                if(InternetUtils.checkForInternet(context))
                {
                    fetchJSON();
                    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        //new array list that will hold the filtered data
        ArrayList<ProductModelClass> filteredNames = new ArrayList<>();

        //looping through existing elements
        for (ProductModelClass s : productModelClassList) {
            //if the existing elements contains the search input
            if (s.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                //adding the element to filtered list

                filteredNames.add(s);
            }

        }

        Log.d("wwwee",text);

        //calling a method of the adapter class and passing the filtered list

            productAdapter.filterList(filteredNames);


    }

    private void fetchJSON() {


        //creating a string request to send request to the url
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.jsonURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("tennis", response.toString());

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("true")) {

                                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                                    ProductModelClass playersModel = new ProductModelClass();
                                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    playersModel.setId(dataobj.getInt("id"));
                                    playersModel.setName(dataobj.getString("name"));
                                    playersModel.setCountry(dataobj.getString("country"));
                                    playersModel.setCity(dataobj.getString("city"));
                                    playersModel.setImgURL(dataobj.getString("imgURL"));
                                    productModelClassList.add(playersModel);

                                }
                            }

                            recyclerViewProduct.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

                            productAdapter= new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),productModelClassList);
                            recyclerViewProduct.setAdapter(productAdapter);
                            shimmerContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
                            shimmerContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //adding the string request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       /* if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }*/

        if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, CartListActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }


        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            sharedPrefLogout.logout();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();



        if (id == R.id.nav_about) {


            // fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new Menu1Fragment()).commit();
            Intent intent=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (id == R.id.nav_user) {

            setTitle("Home");
           // fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new Menu1Fragment()).commit();
            Intent intent=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_uploadImages) {
            //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new Menu1Fragment()).commit();
            Intent intent=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, UploadImagesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


           // fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new Menu2Fragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_order_history) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, OrderHistoryTabActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            shareIt();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_helpdesk) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this, HelpdeskActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<ProductModelClass> productModelClassList;


    public ProductAdapter(Context ctx, List<ProductModelClass> productModelClassList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.productModelClassList = productModelClassList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_product_item_list,null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        Picasso.get().load(productModelClassList.get(position).getImgURL()).into(holder.imageView_product);
        holder.txtview_itemname.setText(productModelClassList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtview_model.setText(productModelClassList.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.txtview_desc.setText(productModelClassList.get(position).getCity());


        holder.editTextQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    holder.editTextQuantity.setHint("");
                else
                    holder.editTextQuantity.setHint("quantity");
            }
        });


        holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ProductModelClass item = new ProductModelClass();


                int pid= productModelClassList.get(position).getId();
                String image=productModelClassList.get(position).getImgURL();
                String name = holder.txtview_itemname.getText().toString();
                String country = holder.txtview_model.getText().toString();
                String city =   holder.txtview_desc.getText().toString();

                ProductListDBHelper dbHelper = new ProductListDBHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                dbHelper.insertData(pid,image,name,country,city,database);
                Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "Product Added to the Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dbHelper.close();



            }
        });


       }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  productModelClassList.size();
    }

    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText editTextQuantity;
        ImageView imageView_product;
        TextView txtview_itemname,txtview_model,txtview_desc,addToCart;
        Spinner spinner;

        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView_product=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_product);
            txtview_itemname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
            txtview_model=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemModelNum);
            txtview_desc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDescriptions);
            editTextQuantity=itemView.findViewById(R.id.edttxt_quantity);

            addToCart=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtvAddToCart);

          //  spinner=(Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuantity);


        }
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<ProductModelClass> filterdNames) {
        this.productModelClassList = filterdNames;
        Log.d("dlkd", String.valueOf(productModelClassList));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the Android lifecycle.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state

Activity restore > TextView restore > TextView setText > afterTextChanged

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have initialized **`productAdapter`** before calling

```
productAdapter.filterList(filteredNames);
```

as in yourt code `productAdapter` is assigning the value after fetching the json but `afterTextChanged` of search_edittext `TextChangedListener` will call before that for empty text on search_edittext. Thats the reason it is throwing NullPointerException.

Add a check for

```
if(productAdapter !=null){
 filter(editable.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing. You get NullPointerException when you call an object which is not initialized first. So in your code, I can see you are initializing an adapter when you get a response from a network call which is your 'fetchJSON' method in NavDrawerActivity. So you can solve this issue in two ways,

1. Initialize the ProductAdapter in onCreate of your activity and when you get a response from a network call (which is in fetchJSON method), just refresh the adapter by calling productAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
2. Use a if condition in afterTextChanged where you will check whether adapter is initialized or not eg.

   if(productAdapter!=null){
     filter(editable.toString());
   }